UML Namespaces and "isDistinguishableFrom"
This operation is described on p. 91 of the UML 2.5.1 specification under section 7.8.9.7 "Operations" for the NamedElement description. I am trying to understand how it can be done as specified:

The query isDistinguishableFrom() determines whether two NamedElements
may logically co-exist within a Namespace. By default, two named elements
are distinguishable if (a) they have types neither of which is a
kind of the other or (b) they have different names.

Which programming languages exist where two identical names can coexist in the same scope just because they have different types? Are there any?
Doesn't work in C++ apparently:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a = 4711;
  const char *a = "Hello, Strange World";
  ++a;
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
  
/////////

bob@my_laptop:~/code$ g++ -c strange.cpp 
strange.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
strange.cpp:6:15: error: conflicting declaration ‘const char* a’
    6 |   const char *a = "Hello, Strange World";
      |               ^
strange.cpp:5:7: note: previous declaration as ‘int a’
    5 |   int a = 4711;
      |       ^


Of course, some types override this operation such as BehavioralFeature in order to take into account the signature of a function which can be overloaded by a different function with the same name.

With type, I guess they mean metatype. So you can have a Class, a Property, and an Operation all with the same name.

In C++ you can very well give the same name to class  and either a function or an instance, because there is absolutely no confusion possible.

In C++ you can very well give the same name to class and either a function or an instance, because there is absolutely no confusion possible. Nasty example: https://ideone.com/VAu9TB - Of course I would not recommend such practice neither in C++ nor in UML.

@Christophe Thanks for the example; I was about to ask you for one! Last night I started re-reading the C++ standard about name lookup rules. I played around with your example, but i think the name lookup doesn't consider all declarations of MyType; I couldn't find a way for actually USING both i and t in the same scope. However, I am more interested in the motivation for defining the UML constraint as it is. Of course, it would have to be redefined for a C++ profile. But what languages could actually use it this way?

The UML specification for Variable indicates that, via ConnectableElement, it is a TypedElement and therefore a NamedElement -- no big surprise here, but this means that the Variable name could be the same as some other Variable within the same namespace if they were of different types, and the UML constraint would still be satisfied. However, if it is as @GeertBellekens says, the intent of the constraint was to check the metaclass type instead of the modeled type, since both would be of type Variable, they would have to have different names.

If you read further you'll find the OCL specification for this same constraint.
body: (self.oclIsKindOf(n.oclType()) or n.oclIsKindOf(self.oclType())) implies
ns.getNamesOfMember(self)->intersection(ns.getNamesOfMember(n))->isEmpty()

In this formal expression we see that the types mentioned in the plaintext explanation refer to .oclType()
If we then check the OCL specification we find

oclType() : Classifier
Evaluates to the type of which self is an instance.
post: self.oclIsTypeOf(result)

Since this OCL constraint is written in the metamodel of UML it is clear that this refers to the Meta-type of the element, and not the classifier known as type.
So this means that within a namespace it is allowed to have

Class with name A
Association with name A
Operation with name A

Since neither Class, Association or Operation are a KindOf each other.
It is not allowed to have

Datatype with name A
Enumeration with name A

Since Enumeration is a KindOf Datatype
This corresponds pretty much to the way the naming constraints are implemented in most programming languages.

The language called UML isn’t committed to representing any kind of thing in reality, be it types of animals or Java classes. Thus, if you want to translate UML to some more-constrained language, you will need to impose those constraints on your usage of UML. Sometimes you even need to augment UML with a profile to make the language as expressive as some other language, e.g., OWL.
In simpler terms, what works in UML doesn’t have to work in C++.

What is UML supposed to be good for? How many projects are implemented in OWL compared to languages such as C++ and Java? I would like to think that there is still some direct relationship between the usefulness of UML and its implementations. Besides, you didn't answer my question: "Which programming languages exist where two identical names can coexist in the same scope just because they have different types? Are there any?"

@RobertHairgrove I wouldn't bet. Ever heard of esoteric languages? There are some big weirdos. P.S.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language

@qwerty_so LOL! I never heard of any of these. But I learned something new today, thanks!

@Jim_L You are right, of course, that a C++ profile would override and/or add any constraints that it likes.

@RobertHairgrove the Alf language is meant to be fully compatible with UML. I believe two names of different types can coexist.

@JimL. Interesting ... there are actually two programming languages by the name of Alf, but different types. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Logic_Functional_programming_language So I guess the name passes the constraint definition!

@RobertHairgrove I meant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_UML#fUML_and_ALF

First of all modeling is also a question of judgement, and it is therefore left to the modeler to use the possibilities of UML wisely.
Even in C++ you can have in rare cases elements of different kind sharing the same name in the same scope without any confusion:
class MyTest {}; 
int MyTest() { return 1; };

But despite the language allowing it,  most developers will avoid it because of the confusion.
More broadly, in a C++ project, the executable's filename MyTest could have the same name than the MyTest class that it implements. In UML both the artefact annd the class could have the same name in the same package without any confusion.
Last but not least you could imagine to implement a component exposing a COM interface that has the same name that the c++ class that implements component. Again, this microsoft c++ reality can make sense and justify using the same name for different elements of different metaclasses in UML.
As Geert explained, you could have an association and a class having the same name. This seems absurd in most of the cases, doesn't it? On the other hand there are association-classes that are at the same time an association and a class and both must have the same name (there's even a rule about that). So this apparent UML absurd flexibility makes perfectly sense in some cases. Wouldn't it be allowed, wouldn't it be possible to consistently address the naming of association classes, in line their semantics.
So in conclusion, while in most of the case this naming possibility should be avoided by the modeler on his/her own initiative, there are nevertheless cases where it is justified and even necessary, and this is probably the reason of UML's flexibility in this regard.
